# Asp.net Boilerplate - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

[image: error image]

Used ASP.NET boilerplate to create Multi Page Web Application
(includes login, register, user, role and tenant management pages 
 https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates)

Getting below mention error while building the project. Kindly point me a direction to sort the mention issue.

Thank-you.

**Error -**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'organizationUnitRepository' of 'AbpRoleManager.AbpRoleManager(AbpRoleStore, IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, ILogger>, IPermissionManager, ICacheManager, IUnitOfWorkManager, IRoleManagementConfig, IRepository, IRepository)'   test.Core   C:\test\4.6.0\aspnet-core\src\test.Core\Authorization\Roles\RoleManager.cs  25  Active

Answer (score 3):

Easily fixed - just add the required params yourself.

```
public class RoleManager : AbpRoleManager<Role, User>
{
    public RoleManager(
        RoleStore store,
        IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<Role>> roleValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        ILogger<AbpRoleManager<Role, User>> logger,
        IPermissionManager permissionManager,
        ICacheManager cacheManager,
        IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
        IRoleManagementConfig roleManagementConfig,
        IRepository<OrganizationUnit, long> organizationUnitRepository,
        IRepository<OrganizationUnitRole, long> organizationUntiRoleRepository)
        : base(
              store,
              roleValidators,
              keyNormalizer,
              errors, logger,
              permissionManager,
              cacheManager,
              unitOfWorkManager,
              roleManagementConfig,
              organizationUnitRepository,
              organizationUntiRoleRepository)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you are trying to model your RoleManager after the one that designed to work with Abp your parameters don't match the ones that are required for the base class.

**This link relates to the Sample they provide.**
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/test/Abp.Zero.SampleApp/Roles/RoleManager.cs

**This link refers to the implementation of the AbpRoleManager class itself.**
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.ZeroCore/Authorization/Roles/AbpRoleManager.cs